# How to list all requests to udp sockets?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, packet-analyzer

I'm operating a couple of server daemons that use udp to communicate with large number of clients. How do I find and list out all the active udp *"connections"* that are talking to the servers in order to estimate the num of active clients that are connected to the server daemons? I couldn't think of an easy way to do this besides sniffing the packets with tshark or tcpdump and look at the source ip of udp packets going to the server daemons and yes, I know UDP is connectionless and stateless protocol.

Comment: Since there's no state/status/anything for UDP connections nowhere, probably the only way is logging some info for each packet (sent or received). Maybe redirect it with iptables to some daemon that'll log IPs or keep statistics or something.

Comment: Define "*active* udp connection".

Comment: @Sandman4 maybe he wants to list all requests to UDP sockets.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is difficult to track down UDP requests without a sniffer, so some context is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo lsof -iUDP`

Answer (score 11):

UDP is a stateless protocol - so, no states.

To see what's listening for UDP:

```
netstat -lnpu
```

The equivalent command on modern linux:

```
ss -lnpu
```

Answer (score 6):

You could log every UDP connection using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "udp connection: "
```

Perhaps you might want to limit it to some ports. Check [documentation here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) or, preferably, `man iptables`.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned UDP is connection-less so state isn't tracked in the standard locations you might look.

One method you could use is simply setup some simple netfilter rules that use the `--state` option.  This will force netfilter to track state related to UDP.  Once you setup rules then you can use a tool like [conntrack](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/conntrack-tools/index.html) to look at the netfilter state table.  Here for example is what one of my system looks like.  You can see there are a couple systems that are frequently communicating to udp/1194 (OpenVPN).

```
root@enterprise:# conntrack  -L -p udp
udp      17 173 src=192.168.32.1 dst=192.168.32.10 sport=41179 dport=1194 packets=2072 bytes=188058 src=192.168.32.10 dst=192.168.32.1 sport=1194 dport=41179 packets=2081 bytes=201185 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=1
udp      17 175 src=192.168.32.26 dst=192.168.32.10 sport=57440 dport=1194 packets=806767 bytes=154637738 src=192.168.32.10 dst=192.168.32.26 sport=1194 dport=57440 packets=1265893 bytes=1588040830 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=1
```

Your netfilter rules could be as simple as this.

```
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, assuming that the iproute2 is installed, you can run the [ss](http://linuxaria.com/pills/ss-iproute2-linux?lang=en) command to pull udp sockets like so:

```
ss -u
```

Or all udp sockets, with the associated process:

```
[root@kerberos ks]# ss -u -pa
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                       Peer Address:Port   
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kerberos                                               *:*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:mdns                                                  *:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",1613,13))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:rquotad                                               *:*        users:(("rpc.rquotad",1872,3))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kerberos-iv                                               *:*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:sunrpc                                                *:*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:ipp                                                   *:*        users:(("cupsd",1687,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                       192.168.15.100:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,23))
UNCONN      0      0                                          172.16.15.1:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,22))
UNCONN      0      0                                            127.0.0.1:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,21))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,16))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:892                                                   *:*        users:(("rpc.mountd",1888,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:896                                                   *:*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:32769                                                 *:*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:nfs                                                   *:*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:syslog                                                *:*        users:(("rsyslogd",1506,1))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:42375                                                 *:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",1613,14))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:pftp                                                  *:*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,8))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:snmp                                                  *:*        users:(("snmpd",1949,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:37802                                                 *:*        users:(("squid",2124,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:bootps                                                *:*        users:(("dhcpd",1987,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:tftp                                                  *:*        users:(("xinetd",1968,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:971                                                   *:*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,5))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kpasswd                                               *:*        users:(("kadmind",1926,6))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kerberos                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,11))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kerberos                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,9))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kerberos-iv                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,10))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kerberos-iv                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,8))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::sunrpc                                               :::*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,9))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feda:8094:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,26))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe52:8f66:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,30))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feea:63a8:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,29))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe16:15c3:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,28))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe75:8012:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,27))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feb3:4da8:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,25))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,20))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,19))
UNCONN      0      0                                                  ::1:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,18))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,17))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::892                                                  :::*        users:(("rpc.mountd",1888,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::896                                                  :::*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,10))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::32769                                                :::*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::nfs                                                  :::*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::syslog                                               :::*        users:(("rsyslogd",1506,2))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::pftp                                                 :::*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,10))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kpasswd                                              :::*        users:(("kadmind",1926,8))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kpasswd                                              :::*        users:(("kadmind",1926,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::59603                                                :::*        users:(("squid",2124,8))
[root@kerberos ks]# ss -upa
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                       Peer Address:Port   
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kerberos                                               *:*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:mdns                                                  *:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",1613,13))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:rquotad                                               *:*        users:(("rpc.rquotad",1872,3))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kerberos-iv                                               *:*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:sunrpc                                                *:*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:ipp                                                   *:*        users:(("cupsd",1687,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                       192.168.15.100:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,23))
UNCONN      0      0                                          172.16.15.1:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,22))
UNCONN      0      0                                            127.0.0.1:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,21))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:ntp                                                   *:*        users:(("ntpd",1976,16))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:892                                                   *:*        users:(("rpc.mountd",1888,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:896                                                   *:*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:32769                                                 *:*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:nfs                                                   *:*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:syslog                                                *:*        users:(("rsyslogd",1506,1))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:42375                                                 *:*        users:(("avahi-daemon",1613,14))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:pftp                                                  *:*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,8))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:snmp                                                  *:*        users:(("snmpd",1949,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:37802                                                 *:*        users:(("squid",2124,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:bootps                                                *:*        users:(("dhcpd",1987,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:tftp                                                  *:*        users:(("xinetd",1968,6))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:971                                                   *:*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,5))
UNCONN      0      0                                                    *:kpasswd                                               *:*        users:(("kadmind",1926,6))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kerberos                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,11))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kerberos                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,9))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kerberos-iv                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,10))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kerberos-iv                                              :::*        users:(("krb5kdc",1935,8))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::sunrpc                                               :::*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,9))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feda:8094:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,26))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe52:8f66:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,30))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feea:63a8:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,29))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe16:15c3:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,28))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:fe75:8012:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,27))
UNCONN      0      0                              fe80::fc54:ff:feb3:4da8:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,25))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,20))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,19))
UNCONN      0      0                                                  ::1:ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,18))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::ntp                                                  :::*        users:(("ntpd",1976,17))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::892                                                  :::*        users:(("rpc.mountd",1888,9))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::896                                                  :::*        users:(("rpcbind",1569,10))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::32769                                                :::*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::nfs                                                  :::*       
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::syslog                                               :::*        users:(("rsyslogd",1506,2))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::pftp                                                 :::*        users:(("rpc.statd",1643,10))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::2e0:4cff:fe90:40eb:kpasswd                                              :::*        users:(("kadmind",1926,8))
UNCONN      0      0                             fe80::226:2dff:fe47:309f:kpasswd                                              :::*        users:(("kadmind",1926,7))
UNCONN      0      0                                                   :::59603                                                :::*        users:(("squid",2124,8))
```

Here are additional examples you can use with ss, including get connections per process.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html

Comment: Again, how can udp have a connection? `ss` only displays UDP sockets not **connection**.

Comment: Bad choice of words. That said, I asked for clarification from Flit, as it is not clear what he is trying to do.

Comment: What's the difference between `ss -pa` and `ss -upa` in the example?
Should half be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285377/155090), i've found that the following `ss` syntax works for me:

```
ss -u state CLOSE
```

… because "listening" UDP sockets are like "closed" TCP sockets.